# Have there ever been any programs or other efforts from Israel just to grant a citizenship for "safe" Gazans?

Tags: israel, history

By "safe" I mean not dangerous: not willing to commit or support the war action against Israel and ready to integrate into society enough like knowing Hebrew. I understand that somebody calling to kill or drive away all citizens of a country is unlikely to be offered the citizenship of that country.

It could probably be less controversial method to reduce the size of hostile Gaza population than just by bombings. The size of Gaza population is 2,375,259 and the size of Israeli population is about 9,849,440. Other things aside, that much a country likely could just integrate.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a process for permanent residents of Israel to become citizens. It is a long and drawn-out process, [potentially taking years](https://lawoffice.org.il/en/israeli-citizenship-for-residents-of-east-jerusalem/), much longer than the process of citizenship by immigration for Jews or those with Jewish ancestry.

There is also [a process](https://www.gov.il/en/service/apply_for_asylum_in_israel) for refugees (including those from Palestine) to seek asylum in Israel and thus gain permanent residency. They could then seek citizenship after meeting the requirements for that process. Approximately 21% of Israel's citizen population are Palestinian Arabs, whether they (or their parents/grandparents) had been incorporated into the new 1948 state or whether they had gained citizenship later on.<sup>1</sup> They enjoy full rights of citizenship and are equal under the law to Jewish (and other non-Arab) citizens.<sup>2</sup>

Therefore, yes, in theory there is a mechanism for Palestinians, including Gazans, to become Israeli citizens, but as far as I can tell, Israel is making no effort to make this any easier of a process. In fact, as other answerers have pointed out, Israel's right wing (which is currently in power) is adamantly against establishing a right of return for Palestinians who lived in British Palestine before 1948. Therefore, in practice, it is extremely unlikely that a Palestinian from Gaza would be able to obtain Israeli citizenship under "normal" circumstances, and effectively impossible during wartime.

---

<sup>1</sup>This figure does not include Palestinians living in East Jerusalem since 1948, who are considered permanent residents but not citizens (unless they have separately obtained citizenship), nor does it include Palestinians living in the West Bank or Gaza, who have no legal status in Israel and live under Israeli martial law, Palestinian civil law, or the Hamas terrorist regime, depending on where exactly they live, all of which are oppressive and brutal to varying degrees.

<sup>2</sup>There are several Arab political parties within the Israeli legislature, and during the brief period a couple of years ago in which the political center took control of the government from Netanyahu, they were even a part of the governing coalition. There is also [an Arab sitting on the Israeli Supreme Court](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khaled_Kabub). That being said, it is not the case that Israeli Arabs do not experience racism or discrimination. For instance, they are often ethnically profiled by police forces, and there is a clear income gap between Arab and Jewish families. However, the Israeli Arab experience is significantly different from the oppressive occupation faced by West Bank residents.

Comment: Should "living in East Jerusalem since 1948" be changed to "living in East Jerusalem since before 1967"?  Israel lost East Jerusalem to Jordan in 1948 and took it back in 1967.

Comment: Also, is the income gap (and I know it sounds like I am nitpicking, but it seems important) counted in average earnings or average life-time income capacity?  Israeli arabs are not required to go through the military service.  3 years of extra earnings + 2month every year (is that still the case?) would produce a higher overall income than simply a higher wage.  They also have regions with reduce or no tax, don't they?  Someone explained to me once why they can economically sell groceries cheaper than Jewish Israelies, but I don't remember anymore

Comment: While the answer is good (+1) the following is a misstatement: *Israel's right wing (which is currently in power) is adamantly against establishing a right of return for Palestinians who lived in British Palestine before 1948.* The *right of return* is equally opposed by the right and the left wings (unless we identify left with extreme left). It equally posed an issue for Rabin, Barak, and Olmert who negotiated with the PA,and pretty much for any Israeli party supporting two-state solution.

Comment: regarding equal rights, In 1950, 46,000 out of the 156,000 Israeli Arabs in Israel were considered **Present absentees**.  They are not permitted to live in the homes they formerly lived in, even if they were in the same area as their home, the property still exists, and they can show that they own it. They are regarded as absent by the Israeli government  source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Present_absentee

Answer (score 19):

- [About 20% of Israeli population are already Palestinians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demographics_of_Israel).
- Some Palestinians get Israeli citizenship via marriage (e.g., [this recent article](https://www.ynetnews.com/article/bj44n81o6) mentions a relative of a high Hamas official married to an Israeli Bedouin.)
- Prior to the Intifadas and construction of the separation barrier, many West Bank and Gaza Palestinians had [permits for working in Israel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israeli_permit_regime_in_the_West_Bank#Work_permits).
- The Palestinian population is growing rapidly - e.g., at the moment [UNRWA counts nearly 6 million Palestinian refugees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palestinian_refugees), mostly descendants of about 750 thousands of refugees from pre-1948 Israel. This does not include the Palestinians indigenous to the West Bank and Gaza. So the solution is not realistic.
- Finally, and this is the most important part - **resettling of some of the Palestinians in Israel is one of the contentious points in the Peace negotiations within the Oslo framework, known as [*the right of return*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palestinian_right_of_return).**

**Remarks:**
Regarding the status of the territories formally annexed by Israel:
*East Jerusalem*
The Residents of *east Jerusalem* has a [streamlined access to citizenship](https://www.iataskforce.org/sites/default/files/resource/resource-2100.pdf) (see also [here](https://lawoffice.org.il/en/israeli-citizenship-for-residents-of-east-jerusalem/)):

> Almost all of the Arabic-speaking population of Jerusalem lives in East Jerusalem, around 350,000 people. Prior to 1967, East Jerusalem was under Jordanian control. After the war,
> Jerusalem was annexed by Israel, but most East Jerusalem residents did not choose to become citizens, during the limited period of time with this was offered. Since then, there have
> periods Israel has not allowed residents to apply for citizenship in most cases, and periods in which they could apply. **Today, East Jerusalem residents can apply for Israeli citizenship
> through a process that is less time-consuming and challenging than it had been in prior years.** Non-Israeli citizen East Jerusalem residents (the vast majority) receive permanent
> residency status—a different category than citizen that entitles them to some rights but not others, as described in the table.

*Golan Heights*
The inhabitants of the Golan Heights (who are mostly Druze) were given the Israeli citizenship when the area was annexed. Some opted out out of fear that the area might return back to Syria, and they would be punish for disloyalty.

**Palestinians vs. Israeli Arabs**
In response to comments: [Palestinian identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palestinian_identity) is a complex issue - some of the non-Jewish population in Israel clearly do not identify themselves as Palestinians, notably Druze and Negev Bedouins. Whether the majority of the Arab population in [Israeli Arab citizens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arab_citizens_of_Israel) should be considered Palestinians, because of their close kinship with those in West Bank and Gaza or whether they should be seen as something different is a matter of debate and their own self-identification. My first comment is thus limited to the terminology used by Wikipedia article on [Demographics of Israel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demographics_of_Israel):

> 21.1% (around 2,080,000 people) are Israeli citizens classified as Arab, some identifying as Palestinian, and including Druze, Circassians, all other Muslims, Christian Arabs, Armenians (which Israel considers "Arab")

Comment: is there an immigration process which allows them to be vetted and get citizenship status?  Either West Bank or Gaza arabs?

Comment: @RadicallyReasonable on what grounds exactly? No country grants its citizenship on demand.

Comment: I didn't say "on demand". I asked if there was a process.  That usually means applying and meeting some criteria for approval.

Comment: @RadicallyReasonable if some people are getting citizenship, as described in the answer, then there is a process. But usually one needs to have a reason for applying a citizenship - e.g., reuniting with one's family. [This article, e.g., provides one example - via marriage](https://www.ynetnews.com/article/bj44n81o6)

Comment: Technically speaking this doesn't answer the Q (either). Unless you can show that the way Arabs were granted Israeli citizenship was dependent on them being "safe" for Israel. Of course, there are various conceptions of "safe". What you say here is that Arabs are "safe" in <20% numbers or so. But the OP uses a different notion of "safe" just linked to individual behavior.

Comment: @Fizz you put the emphasis on being *safe*, which the Q likely didn't intend. The way I understand Q is that it is about giving some Gazans citizenship to relax tensions. This is a bit naïve, because a) there are too many claimants to the citizenship, and b) how many Palestinians will be given citizenship is in itself one of the contentious issues in this conflict.

Comment: Since the OP spends half the Q explaining their notion of "safe", it seemed important enough to me.

Comment: @Fizz I suppose they wanted to rule out direct answers that Israel cannot give citizenship to those who intend to attack it.

Comment: About 20% of Israel's population are *Arabs*.  Not all of them self-identify as "Palestinians".

Comment: @dan04 you can follow the link in the answer for more precise numbers. Bedouins, druze and other groups are rather small in comparison.

Comment: The "right of return" is more than resettling in Israel - I (and FWIW, the wiki article also seems to) understand this to encompass the right to property owned before the "nakba", so not mere citizenship.

Comment: @RogerV.: I think you've misunderstood dan04's comment. (S)he's saying that many people that you're labeling as "Palestinians" do not label themselves that way, and arguing that you shouldn't do so either. (See [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arab_citizens_of_Israel#Self-identification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arab_citizens_of_Israel#Self-identification) for some context.)

Comment: @ruakh they are literally blood relatives of the Palestinians in Gaza and WB. One could discuss what is Palestinian identity: if we consider it as a response to Jewish immigration and the creation of Israel, then the experience of those who stayed in 1948 is certainly different from those who became refugees. If we mean by "Palestinians" those who lived in the region prior to the Aliyah, then they are the same people. Israel recognizes this - e.g., they are free from obligation to do military service (unlike Druze or Bedouin).

Comment: @RogerV.: I'm not looking to argue with you; I just wanted to explain dan04's comment, since you'd misunderstood what (s)he was getting at. (Though if I may nitpick: "those who lived in the region prior to the Aliyah" is not quite what you mean; obviously there were Jews, Druze, Bedouins and others in the region before the First Aliyah. It's hard to precisely define a group, even in less-contentious cases!)

Comment: @ruakh Palestinian identity is a complex issue - so I agree that "Palestinian" is an ambiguous term. Not sure though that "Israeli Arabs" is a better designation - are Bedouins not Arabs?

Comment: @ruakh I added a remark summarizing our discussion.

Comment: @dan04 Regarding your earlier comment - please see the discussion with at_ruakh above, and the remark I added to the answer.

Answer (score 8):

The problem with this idea is Israel's Zionist tenets.

If they admit large numbers of Palestinians, the Israeli state will cease to be controlled and dominated by a majority who are so-called Jewish in origin.

They already have a large minority of so-called Arab Israelis, who are non-Jewish in origin and were absorbed in 1948 on the founding of Israel upon the territory where these Arab Israelis already lived (or their ancestors were).

The demographics are also worsening from the Zionist perspective. The Arab Israelis are successful at reproducing and increasing their numbers, whereas the Jewish Israelis are less so, and are propped up in significant numbers by new migrant settlers.

(EDIT: per the comments, the birth rates between Jewish and Arab Israelis may have converged more in recent years, but it remains true to say that the demographic balance is still a significant concern of Zionists. The issue of Palestinian - non-Israeli - fecundity is also a concern for any proposal that involves absorbing the Palestinians.)

The Zionists also tend to have a strong racial or heritable flavour to their definition of being Jewish, so that conversions to Judaism are not necessarily satisfactory to them.

The actual amount of slack between the tipping point is much smaller than nine million.

Comment: 1. The Jewish population in general, is reproducing at a slightly higher rate than the Arab-Israeli population - thanks to Israel's large orthodox community. 2. "strong racial defenition of being Jewish" - Israel is comprised of Jews of literally all colors and shapes. 3. Converting all Palestinians to Judaism, sounds like a wierd idea. 4. "so-called Jewish" - why not "Jewish"?

Comment: @Jacob3, (1) that's not my understanding, but I stand to be corrected. See Wiki under heading "Population growth rate": https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demographics_of_Israel. (2) My actual phrasing was "racial or heritable flavour", and my point is not that Israel is particularly discriminatory on colour or shape in the conventional sense, but that many Zionists root their definition of "Jewish" in biology rather than the cultural practice of Judaism. (3) It's not a weird idea if the point is to integrate Palestinians into a state that could still claim to be Jewish. (1/2)

Comment: (4) I say "so-called" because the definition of Jewish can be vague, vary across context, and be highly contested, and I want to mark that I'm only talking in conventional language. (2/2)

Comment: Well, per your wiki  link, the Jews vs Muslims growth numbers appear to have evened out, but only since 2018 or so...

Comment: @Steve, So peole who by majority wish to annyhilate Israel, because all of the middle east (and beyond) is "Muslim Land", will be converted to Judaism? By force? Reeducation? And is it only because of Israel's perception of Judaism that this will be deemed futile conversions?

Comment: @Fizz, I might not have updated my knowledge of older facts. The overall situation over a period of time is still consistent with what I've said, but I've added an edit to the answer anyway.

Comment: @Jacob3, the issue is not whether every Palestinian would convert. The OP asked about "safe Gazans" being integrated. My point is that Zionists are not attempting to evangelise Judaism or recruit adherents, and would find it awkward and undesirable if there were a large number of earnest conversions. The gist of my answer is that Zionism incorporates tenets that make them irreconcilable to the proposed integration the OP asks about

Comment: The fundamental problem is the Jews security cannot be reasonably guaranteed without them having the government of some land somewhere in the world. The Arabs have plenty of this and believe the Jews should not have it at all.

Comment: @Joshua, such a "fundamental problem" is a political claim of Zionists. Their treatment of "Arabs" as a bloc is also as ludicrous as saying that the Europeans have plenty of space so they won't mind if Zionists occupy half of France. Not only would the French mind, but there would be considerable solidarity from other nations not because they all particularly love the French, but because they don't like the idea of Zionists arrogantly thinking they can just seize land anywhere they like at any time they like.

Comment: @Steve: Your claims would have merit if it weren't for the fact that at the time of the Israeli war for independence, all the other Arab nations pushed the Jews out. For that they should have absorbed all the Palestianians (much smaller than the number of Jews pushed out) but they did not, wanting to use them as political ammo.

Comment: @Joshua, and at various times European nations have also "pushed Jews out" or required conversion. It doesn't legitimise your idea that the Arabs are a single bloc that can be negotiated with as a whole or all their territory treated as fungible. If you seize half of France, you're not attacking "Europe", you're simply attacking France, and you merely worry the other nations that you might do the same to them or otherwise do them harm. Israel as a geopolitical tool of the West, is also significant in unifying opposition from a crew of Arab nations that are otherwise not necessarily bedfellows.

Comment: Before 1948 there was no such people as Palestinians. The people living in Jerusalem called themselves Syrians or an Arab tribal name.

Comment: @Joshua, the same essential point is true of Israelis, except most of them are not even traceable to anyone living in Jerusalem in 1948. The real problem though is that the Gazans are part of the de facto population that Israel administers because it has conquered the territory, both that on which the Gazans live now and that on which they previously lived. The problem is that Israel has no formula for their absorbtion and pacification, only fantasies that a pan-Arabic nation might help them redistribute their brutalised foes, or that extermination might be possible if redistribution isn't.

Comment: That's because that people can't be pacified except by a dictatorship. Give me enough power to sit upon Gaza and displace Hamas and enough money to build industry anew and I will show you a solution; but for reasons that ought to be obvious this can only be done by somebody other than Israel. Maybe when two generations have passed and Islam is tempered like has happened in Egypt these people can be handed a Republic again.

Comment: Are you suggesting that Zionism is a bad thing? Just to confirm. Also, nothing has been tempered in Egypt, as we've seen with the elected Islamic Brotherhood government there just recently (Islamic Brotherhood is a political sibling of Hamas).

Comment: (+1)  days after the UN vote, Ben-Gurion  stated:

the total population of the Jewish State at the time of its establishment will be about one million, including almost 40% non-Jews. Such a [population] composition does not provide a stable basis for a Jewish State. This [demographic] fact must be viewed in all its clarity and acuteness. With such a [population] composition, there cannot even be absolute certainty that control will remain in the hands of the Jewish majority... There can be no stable and strong Jewish state so long as it has a Jewish majority of only 60%

Answer (score 8):

The framing of this question assumes a Western liberal mindset, where learning the language, being adequately educated, integrating and having a willingness to be a productive law-abiding citizen are often considered sufficient conditions to allow one to immigrate to the country.

Israel does not operate this way. It is an expressly Jewish state with a unique concern with its demographic balance. It does not define itself as a "state of its citizens" as most Western countries do, but rather fundamentally associates itself with an ethnic group.

This is why the [right of return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palestinian_right_of_return) of Palestinian refugees ethnically cleansed in the [Nakba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nakba) is considered a non-starter for Israelis in negotiations. It is the one thing that the Israelis have never and will never budge on, as it threatens the Jewishness of the state. Those interested in entry to Israel—including those with legitimate ties to the land like the indigenous Palestinians—are not judged by the "content of their character" (Martin Luther King) but their Jewish genealogy.

Comment: This is wrong. If a company in Israel wants to hire you, it is not that hard to get a working visa for a couple of years. Obviously, as in many Western countries, you need some sort of wanted skill for this. The permanent residency visa is a bit harder to get, but not impossible if you were already there for a while with the temporary working or studying visa (or you can simply marry an Israeli citizen). Lastly, non-Jewish foreigners may even naturalize after living there for at least three years while holding permanent residency and demonstrating proficiency in the Hebrew language.

Comment: This is such a strange answer, not because it's wrong about Israel -- though it is -- but because it's wrong about the Western liberal countries that most people on this site live in and should hopefully know something about. The only people who think their countries' immigration laws are as liberal as you suggest, are people who think their countries are letting in too many immigrants and need to crack down.

Answer (score 5):

In early 2023 Israel [passed](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-middle-east-64654634) a law to revoke citizenship of Arabs involved in attacks.

> Israel has passed a law to revoke the citizenship of Israeli Arabs convicted of terrorism and who get financial aid from the Palestinian Authority (PA). [...]
>
> The monthly stipends offered by the PA to Palestinian prisoners who have carried out attacks on Israelis, or their families, have long been highly contentious.
>
> Israel describes them as a "pay for slay" policy which encourages violence.

So the law you look for exists in a sense, but "in reverse".

Comment: This is possible not only in Israel. E.g. [*The revocation of French nationality may be decided in the following cases: You've been convicted of a crime or a offense constituting a undermining the fundamental interests of the Nation. You have been convicted of a crime or an offense constituting a act of terrorism. etc.*](https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F32827?lang=en) Also, this doesn't really answer the question, even though somewhat related.

Comment: Interesting. But what do you do after revoking the citizenship - you are effectively making someone "stateless". So do you dump them in refugee camps?

Comment: But likely no country would offer citizenship for the persons "involved in attacks" against that country and unless they cannot, would try to revoke it.

Comment: @Stančikas: Confederate officers did get their US citizenship back.  Of course, that was after the CSA surrendered and got reabsorbed by the USA.  It wouldn't have been offered *during* the war.

Comment: @sfxedit the linked article explains it.

Comment: @sfxedit In practice in France I believe this measure is only applied to people with double nationality.

Comment: @sfxedit the law provides them to be deported to the Palestinian Authority, and is conditioned on the Palestinian Authority actually recognizing them as its subjects (through providing funding and support). So in essence, the law claims that by acting on behalf of the PA (committing acts of violence for which the PA compensated them) these people took upon themselves the PA citizenship and are no longer Israeli citizens.

Answer (score -1):

The main question you should be asking yourself is **why**? Why would Israel want to absorb *anyone* from any neighboring country?

Israel has no interest in Gaza, neither the territory nor the population. It doesn't need it and doesn't want it. Why would it want to grant anything to anyone there?

Similarly, you don't see anyone asking "why doesn't US just give all the Canadians its citizenship". Gaza is it's own country, with it's own population, it's own government, and it's own army. They're at war with Israel, have been for a very long time, and there's no reason for Israel to give any concessions to anyone there.

If anything, you would want to ask why **Egypt** doesn't want to absorb Gaza, and didn't want even when it controlled it (between the wars of 1948 and 1967). As opposed to Jordan, which annexed the West Bank and Jerusalem and granted its citizenship to the residents, Egypt never annexed Gaza and never gave Gazans any rights. Egypt also refused to accept Gaza back as part of the peace treaty with Israel in 1979.

Comment: Gaza is a  site for those refuge Palestinians who fled or were expelled during the 1948 Palestine war, by Israel. Not that totally not your business

Comment: @Stančikas that doesn't actually address what I said. Very few of these people are still alive. And it's my business just as it is yours.

Comment: Like 1/3 of the Israeli cabinet seems to want to establish settlements in Gaza, again. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R_Z6z5xyJJk ; https://www.timesofisrael.com/12-ministers-call-to-resettle-gaza-encourage-gazans-to-leave-at-jubilant-conference/?utm_source=article_hpsidebar&utm_medium=desktop_site&utm_campaign=for-most-palestinians-october-7s-savagery-is-literally-unbelievable-blame-the-tv-news

Comment: @Fizz  yeah, 1/3rd of the most right-wing government possible, so not really a meaningful amount. This government only exists until the war is over, so wouldn't take what the extremists in it want as a long-term state strategy.

Comment: Ha, ha. Do you know how many settlements in the West Bank got started without overt gov't approval? It's enough for the gov't not to challenge the would be settlers. Which they're likely to do if their continued stay in power depends on people like Ben-Gvir, who's minister of police among other things.

Comment: @Fizz There's an actual explicit law forbidding settlements in Gaza (or in fact forbidding any Israeli citizens from even crossing into Gaza strip), something that wasn't there when the West Bank settlements started in the 1970s. So the situation is slightly different. Believe me, a lot of people in Israel would be very happy to see a few of Ben Gvir supporters go to prison for violating this law.